# Java Sub vs Superclass

Tags: java

Superclass

```
/*
 * Max 
 * Hangman 
 * 5/23/18
 * JDK Version 1.8.0
 */
package hangman;

import java.util.Scanner; //Scanner input

public class Hangman {

  public static void main(String[] args) {




}
}
```

subclass

```
/*
 * Max
 * Hangman 
 * 5/23/18
 * JDK Version 1.8.0
 */
package hangman;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PlayHangman {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    int triesCount = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter Secrect Word");
    String secretWord = scn.next();
    System.out.println("Enter max # of tries");
    int triesLimit = scn.nextInt();
    StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder(secretWord.length());
    for(int i=0;i<secretWord.length();i++)
        b.append("*");
    char[] secrectStrCharArr=secretWord.toCharArray(); 
    int charCnt=secretWord.length();
    for(int x = 0;triesCount<triesLimit;triesCount++){
    while(charCnt>=0 ){
        System.out.println("Secrect Word :"+b.toString());
        System.out.println("Guess a letter :");

        char guessChar = scn.next().toCharArray()[0];
        for(int i=0;i<secrectStrCharArr.length;i++){
            if(guessChar==secrectStrCharArr[i])
            { b.setCharAt(i,guessChar);}
            else if(guessChar != secrectStrCharArr[i])
            {triesCount++;System.out.println("Incorrect: "+triesCount);}
    }





}
     }


}
```

When I run the program, nothing happens? I'm using latest version of netbeans and latest JDK 1.8.0 . I have been working on this project in school and it has been running. I transferred the same code and it won't run now. Any ideas why? I tried making a new project and restarting my computer & netbeans and nothing seems to work. I am really dumbfounded on why it isn't working. For example when I run no scanner comes up in the output just "run:BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)". (This isn't all the code but it's cut down for the post)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do because you have 2 main methods, you should only have one, probably in the subclass. If you want to inherit your superclass you need to `extend` it.

```
public class PlayHangman extends hangman{
```

I would recommend reading more about [inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get it up and running.